# rails3 - which is better code for performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

Which is the best practise and gives me better performance ?

For example:

I have statuses table which have 5 records and each record need to be store on separate variable.

Method1:

```
@new_status = Status.find_by_status("NEW")
@inprocess_status = Status.find_by_status("InProcess")
@completed_status = Status.find_by_status("Completed")
@occupied_status = Status.find_by_status("Occupied")
@success_status = Status.find_by_status("Success")
```

Method2:

```
statuses = Status.all
@new_status = statuses.find {|status| status.status == "NEW"}
@inprocess_status = statuses.find {|status| status.status == "InProcess"}
@completed_status = statuses.find {|status| status.status == "Completed"}
@occupied_status = statuses.find {|status| status.status == "Occupied"}
@success_status = statuses.find {|status| status.status == "Success"}
```

Or anyother good way ?

Answer (score 2):

This will be even more performant, as it only makes one query to the db and gets only the necessary amount of data. This is assuming `status` field is unique.

```
statuses = Status.where(
  status: ['NEW', 'InProcess', 'Completed', 'Occupied', 'Success']
).order(:status)

@new_status, @completed_status, @inprocess_status, @occupied_status, @success_status = statuses
```

Comment: Isn't that going to assign the record with the lowest value of "status" to /@new_status, the second lowest to /@completed_status, etc? I think you might have to reorder last line. I'd probably just check the count of statuses as well to make sure that five were found.

Comment: The `order(:status)` will make sure they are in the right order (which should be ascending alphabetically). Yes, I made a few assumptions in my code, like that status is unique and those statuses will exist. The purpose wasn't to show a fool-proof example, the purpose was to provide another, more efficient, alternative to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

If there're 5 million records, method 1 should be better because database query has better performance.

If only 5 records, method 2 is better because there's only one database query. Method 1 has 5 queries, which are very time consuming for a small quantity of records.

Answer (score 1):

You have just 5 records so 5 database queries are going to be very expensive, not at all a good practice.

You can fetch them in memory and assign to instance variables. But I can see a symmetry in `Method2` and it looks like very symmetrical code. I strongly suggest not to write symmetrical code in `ruby`, you can modify it with something like:

```
Status.all.each{|status| instance_variable_set("@#{status.name.downcase}_status" , status ) }
```

It will create instance variables and initialise your instance variables with respective statuses.