# rails 3 find single record from active record collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm using rails v3.0.9

I'm not able to figure out how to use find method on active record collection

What i tried in my console,

```
@customers = Customer.all       # returns collection of records

@customer = @customers.find {|customer| customer.id == 1 } # returns the correct record
```

Now i'm using the same find method in association collection

```
@projects = @customer.projects # returns collection of Project records

@project = @projects.find {|project| project.id == 1 }  # got error
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with ID=1...
```

**Please anyone explain how does the find method differs from above two examples**

Is there any other way to find a record in association collection?

I used Array detect to get my Project record

```
@project = @projects.detect {|project| project.id == 1 }    # returns the correct record
```

Which method is best to find single record from array of active records?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
@customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
```

For example:

```
@customer = Customer.find(1)
# => will return the customer with the id equal to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few opportunities:

```
# this returns the customer with the id 1 - if a customer with id 1 exists!
@customer = Customer.find(1)
@customer = Customer.where(:id => 1).first

# this returns the project with id 1 and customer_id = @customer.id
@customer.projects.find(1)
@customer.projects.where(:id => 1).first
```

Your error simple means, that you do not have a project with id = 1 and customer_id = @customer.id

To answer your question..you should use the where queries..that's the new rails 3 way. All find methods are deprecated in rails 4 and extracted out of the rails core into an extra gem.

Comment: Its fine but Model.find and Model.where clause will execute a database query where as Array methods find and detect will return a object through iterate(without query), So I trying Array methods

Comment: What do you mean? If you have saved objects in the database you always have to query them, to get them out of your database :-)..

Comment: Suppose we've minimum records in table(5 records) and want to store each object in separate variable for further calculation, it is best to use Array methods find and detect instead of ActiveRecord where and find. For example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503221/rails3-which-is-better-code-for-performance